# Generic key string name

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a response for my request however one thing might change and that's the key name. It's always going to be a string but it will be different depending on the request.

These are the possible responses

```
{ someRequest: { message: 'success', status: 200 } }
{ someOtherRequest: { message: 'unauthorized', status: 401 } }
```

Knowing the `someRequest` might change but the other will not I have created this

```
export interface Response<T extends string> {
  [key: T]: { message: string; status: number; }
}
```

but it does not work. I get the

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'

How do I define a generic key string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `[key in T]` instead of `[key: T]`. However, interfaces don't allow this operation, so switch to a type alias instead:

```js
export type Response<T extends string> = {
    [key in T]: { message: string; status: number; };
};
```

Alternatively, use the built-in `Record` type:

```js
export type Response<T extends string> = Record<T, { message: string; status: number; };
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `type` using [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type):

```
type Key = 'someRequest' | 'someOtherRequest';
type Response<T extends Key> = Record<T, { message: string; status: number; }>;

const foo: Response<'someRequest'> = {someRequest: {status: 200, message: 'success'}};
const bar: Response<'someOtherRequest'> = {someOtherRequest: {status: 401, message: 'unauthorized'}};
```

Though, `type Response<T extends string> = ...` does also work, without the need of `Key`. Or use `type Key = 'someRequest' | 'someOtherRequest' | string;` to be able to extend the keys.